# Google Sheets use column made from a formula and use it as numbered data in a Countifs formula

Tags: google-sheets, sum, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

I'm having difficulties with a massive difficult formula, so I need some help.
I need to make an automatic filled document.

My problem is with this sum:

```
    =SUM(
      COUNTIFS(
        A2:A;D2;     // get all models with the same name as in D2;
        B2:B;"2019"; // get all models build this year;
        C2:C;"<5000" // get all models with maximum of 5000 kms;
      )
    )
```

I am pretty far, but stuck on the last part;

The data is imported with JSON:
In column A are all the model names: (+- 500 models);
In column B are the years of manufactory (2010 - 2019);
In column C are the mileage per model (0 - 100000);
This is all automaticly imported by JSON.

In column D I have placed all =unique models (8 models in total);
In column E I want to show the total of all models, but:
- If the car is manufactured THIS YEAR;
- AND if the mileage is LESS then 5000;

**It doesn't work on the mileage; But I don't know how to fix this**

Change "2019" to 'this.year', would also be awesome, doesn't work either;

IS this even possible without changing the JSON data?

I am now trying to do this in Google Sheets, but probably Excel users experienced the same problem?

Comment: Choose one, They are different in their approaches more than they are the same.  With two this is too broad.

Comment: BTW with countifs() the ranges must be the same size and shape.  You start one at row 1 and the others at row 2.  Make them the same size.

Comment: Hi Scot; the first two do work; I hoped it was possible with the formula but then I will update the JSON

Comment: I think the sum result will always same with your countifs result

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
=sum(arrayformula(COUNTIFS(A2:A,{D2:D9},B2:B,"2019",C2:C,"<5000" )))
```

with assumption D2:D9 are your models

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=QUERY(A2:C, 
 "select A,sum(C) 
  where C < 5000 
    and B = "&YEAR(TODAY())&"
  group by A 
  label sum(C)''", 0)
```

[image: 0]